# Xpath selector does not work

Tags: python, html, xpath

[image]I'm quite new in `XPath` and I can't figure out what's wrong with this selector:

```
'//div[@id="records"].//div[@class="record"]'
```

The structure `html`:

The thing is that I want to get all `<div class="record">` elements.
What's wrong please?

EDIT: Elaborated snippet:
[image]

Comment: That selector contains invalid syntax. What were you trying to achieve with `.//`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I want to get only those <div class="record"> which are inside the <div id="records"> tag. I read that if I do "//div..." It would find all divs in html.

Comment: Then a single slash would suffice: `//div[@id="records"]/div[@class="record"]`.

Comment: Thank you. I though that it's not enough since I'tried //div[@id="records"]/a(contains[@href,"firma"]) which does not work and now it doesn't  work neither. '//div[@id="records"]/div[@class="record"]/a[contains(@href,"firma")]' -> it should find all a tags which contains string "firma" inside "href". Do you know what is wrong with that? It should work.

Comment: I don't have enough information to tell what's wrong. Can you post the exact markup you're working with and more of your code? Also, `contains()` is case-sensitive, that may be the problem.

Comment: Ok, so I've added another pic which shows how exactly  html of <div class="record"> looks like. I want to get href where href contains "firma" substring in each <div class="record"> This is my xpath query which does not work: '//div[@id="records"]/div[@class="record"]//a[contains(@href,"firma")]/@href'

Comment: what are you trying to get? the href content?

Comment: yes, all hrefs which contains substrings and are inside those class="record" tags.

Answer (score 0):

## your xpath

wrong syntax, just get rid of the "." and you'll get all the `div` elements with attribute `class="record"`

```
'//div[@id="records"]//div[@class="record"]'
```

if (as you said in the comments) you want to get all anchor elements then try this xpath:

```
'//div[@id="records"]/div[@class="record"]/a[contains(@href,"firma")]'
```